# How can I get Gmail notification in my indicator applet (without leaving Evolution open)?

Tags: panel, indicator, gmail

I'd like to have a Gmail notification service in my Epiphany indicator applet, without leaving Evolution open in the background all the time.  Right now I only get notifications if Evolution is open.  Strangely, this is not the case with Google calendars in Evolution -- evolution can be closed yet I still get applet notifications through the clock/calendar applet.

Comment: For each of the answers, can people also list whether that answer also supports google apps accounts, and whether it supports multiple accounts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Gmail Notifier](https://launchpad.net/gm-notify) is probably the best option for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Search "Ubuntu Software Center" for gm-notify to install.

Answer (score 5):

I use CloudSN (Cloud Services Notification). It supports gmail, google reader, pop3, imap, twitter, identi.ca

http://chuchiperriman.github.com/cloud-services-notifications/ (PPA available)

The best part is that it supports multiple accounts.

[image]

Comment: This is interesting, something new I'd better not mess with, but ... oh, man, supports google reader / identica too? dammit.

Answer (score 3):

I've had good luck with [CheckGmail](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/checkgmail). Has a nice GUI, cool toaster popups, and allows you take actions on emails from the tray.

```
sudo apt-get install checkgmail; checkgmail &
```

Comment: CheckGmail is the only one of these that: 1. Displays the full text of the email. 2. Allows archiving/deleting/marking as read from the popup.

Answer (score 3):

Check out GMailWatcher. It is still in early development stage, but works quite well. I am using it for over a month now. Recommended.

Introductory Blogpost: owaislone.org/blog/2010/jul/gmail-watcher
Launchpad URL: https://launchpad.net/gmailwatcher

PPA

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/ppa 
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gmailwatcher
```