# Is there a Gnome applet for IMAP mail accounts?

Tags: applet, gnome, mail, imap

In the spirit of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80/how-can-i-get-gmail-notification-in-my-indicator-applet-without-leaving-evolutio) question...

Is there an indicator applet that tells me when I've received an email through any IMAP service? If so, where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CloudSN (Cloud Services Notification). It supports gmail, google reader, pop3, imap, twitter, identi.ca

http://chuchiperriman.github.com/cloud-services-notifications/ (PPA available)

The best part is that it supports multiple accounts and notify-osd.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**It is not a real gnome applet per se,**  but you can use **[gnubiff](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gnubiff)**, it sits near the clock, in the notification/indicator applet:

> gnubiff checks for mail within a file,
>   a qmail or MH style dir,  or an IMAP4
>   or POP3 or APOP server.  It can
>   display headers (number,  sender,
>   subject, and date) when new mail has
>   arrived.  While gnubiff is
>   implemented as a GNOME panel applet,
>   it also runs as an  independent icon
>   on the desktop in other environments.